# PowerShell Best Practices: Is it bad to treat a PowerShell script like an advanced batch file?

Tags: powershell, coding-style

I'm self-taught with PowerShell and I've written a few scripts now, some of which are pretty powerful. Despite this, I worry that I might not be using PowerShell in its intended way. Here are my two main concerns:

1. From what I've read, PowerShell scripts should be written in such a way that they can be piped into and also so that they can pipe their output into something else. But the way I wrote my scripts is to be completely stand-alone and output everything to the user via `Write-Host`.
2. Another thing I've read is that when errors come up (for example, you try to read a file but don't have permission), you should use `Write-Error` rather than `Write-Host`. I don't do this, though. I just capture the plain English error message and output it with `Write-Host` so it's more user-friendly for people who don't know anything about PowerShell or coding other than how to run scripts.

Are either of these things heavily frowned upon in the PowerShell community? If I showed one of my powerful, well-commented, easy-to-read scripts to an advanced PowerShell coder, would he scoff at it and call it garbage?

Some of my scripts could be useful to others, but I hesitate to show the code to anybody for fear that my style isn't correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you (over)use Write-Host you are foregoing the power and all you have left is a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that it is expected of a script to use `write-output` rather than `write-host` so that the output can be piped to other scripts etc. Cmdlets and maybe functions can be expected to do that, but not scripts. If you have to display something to the user about the actions that the script is doing, you might as well use `Write-Host`. Note that using `Write-Output` might be good, if you want to log the output of the script to a logfile AND display on the screen to the user. Doing that when you are using `Write-Host` cannot be done easily / efficiently.

`Write-Error` add some additional info that IMO is not necessary. I rarely use `Write-Error`. I use `Write-Host -fore red message` to indicate errors in my scripts. That keeps it nice and simple.

But of course, we can't make statements like always use Write-Output or always use Write-Host etc. It is going to depend on the situation and how you are going to be using the scripts.

Answer (score 2):

> "If I showed one of my powerful, well-commented, easy-to-read scripts"

IMO Best practices cannot be followed all the time by everyone. I think as long as your code does is powerful, easy to read and modify (with comments) and if people find it useful then you don't have to worry about following the best practices but it's better to start implementing best practices in your code slowly.

In SharePoint, the best practise is to write error to logs and event viewers but in some of my projects we email the error details to a specific inbox to check and correct issues imediately. We don't follow the best practise here but we find this useful and effective.

We have many PowerShell scripts which our team uses almost everyday to do quick tasks in our SharePoint servers. They were written by us and we don't follow all the best practices too :)